# Attach collections in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using the entity framework, I am able to attach single objects using

```
entity.Attach();
```

However, I see no method that allows me to add a collection / array of multiple objects to an entity.

Must I loop through each item in the collection and call `entity.Attach()` each time?

Comment: What type is `entity`? Do you mean an ObjectContext, or an EntityReference or EntityCollection, or ...? In each case there isn't an `Attach` method without parameter. It's not clear what you want to attach where.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you must loop through the child collection and `Attach`.

Also, take note that if the entity is modified, `Attach` attaches it to the context `Unmodified` state. You must also set the state to `Modified`.

See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Comment: This is really pain in the @$$. I wish [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450383/exception-in-expression-trees) would work fine.